# R: Assign treatment based on groups with different levels of correlations

Tags: r, variable-assignment, simulation

I want to assign a (non-random) treatment variable based on different correlation levels with a group variable.

E.g. for the following data table:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(123)
dt <- data.table(id=1:1000, group=sample(c(1:4), 1000, replace=T))
```

I want to assign a treatment [0,1] to the groups, where individuals in e.g.  group 4 have a higher probability of getting the treatment. And I also want to be able to change the level of correlation for the assignment.

I know that the *trtObserve()* function from the *simstudy* package does assign treatment depending on other variables.

E.g. one can set a formula to assign probabilities for the assignment:

```
library(simstudy)
formula1 <- c("0.1 + 0.1*group")
dtExp <- trtObserve(dt, formulas = formula1, logit.link = TRUE, grpName = "treatment")
table(dtExp$treatment, dtExp$group)
    1   2   3   4
0 119 120  82  85
1 128 140 163 163
```

But I do not get how the assignment takes place based on the formula.

Can someone explain how the formula is incorporated in the assignment or give an alternative solution to my problem?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the probability that you will have more 4's in your group using the `probs` options in the `sample()` function. You can do this like so:

```
set.seed(123)
dt <- data.table(id=1:1000, group=sample(1:4, size=1000, prob = c(0.1,.2,.2,.5), replace = T))
dt$treatment <- sample(c(0,1), 1000, replace = TRUE)
table(dt$group, dt$treatment)

#      0   1
#  1  46  43
#  2  93 107
#  3  93 105
#  4 269 244
```